# Java8 Collecting data from 2 different object streams to a sorted list of 3rd object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So here's the problem. I have three classes as below:

```
class ObjectClassA
{
    private final long id;
    private final String name;
    private final boolean isReadOnly;
    //<some more fields>

    long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    boolean isReadOnly()
    {
        return this.isReadOnly;
    }
}

class ObjectClassB
{
    private final long id;
    private final String location;
    private final boolean isReadOnly;
    //<some more fields>

    long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    String getLocation()
    {
        return this.location;
    }

    boolean isReadOnly()
    {
        return this.isReadOnly;
    }
}
```

and

```
class ObjectClassC
{
    private final String location;
    private final boolean isReadOnly;
    private final String location;

    String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    boolean isReadOnly()
    {
        return this.isReadOnly;
    }

    String getLocation()
    {
        return this.location;
    }
}
```

I have 2 maps -

```
Map<Id,ObjectClassA> mapObjectClassA
```

and

```
Map<Id,ObjectClassB> mapObjectClassB
```

Both these maps are of the same size. The Id keys are common to both maps. The aim is to iterate over either maps to create a sorted (by `ObjectClassC.name`) `List<ObjectClassC>` objects such that:

```
ObjectClassC.name = ObjectClassA.name
ObjectClassC.isReadOnly = ObjectClassA.isReadOnly || ObjectClassB.isReadOnly
ObjectClassC.location = ObjectClassB.location
```

This is the logic that I have right now is as follows:

```
final List<ObjectClassC> list = 
mapObjectClassA.values()
               .stream()
               .map(a -> {
                    new ObjectClassC(a.getName(),
                                     a.isReadOnly() || mapObjectClassB.get(a.getId).isReadOnly(),
                                     mapObjectClassB.get(a.getId).getLocation())
                })
               .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ObjectClassC::getName))
               .collect(Collectors.<ObjectClassC> toList());
```

My mapping and collection are working fine, but I don't get a sorted collection of `ObjectClassC` objects. Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you post a simple working [mcve]? The `sorted` operation there should sort by names. What output are you getting with a sample input?

Comment: There are quite a few typos in your code. Missing `)` at the end of the `.sorted` line; no `()` on `a.getId`; extra braces round the `new ObjectClassC` part. It really would be better to copy and paste.

Comment: You can't have two fields called `location` in `ObjectClassC`.

Comment: Your two `getId()` methods return a `long`, which is autoboxed to `Long`, but since that is not an `Id`, your map lookups will fail. --- And it's just `Collectors.toList()`. No need to explicitly specify the type.

Comment: Unable to reproduce using [this MCVE](https://ideone.com/F7UPij).

Answer (score 0):

Not so nice, but works.

```
public class MapMerge_38837365 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, A> as = new HashMap();
        as.put(1, new A("Anna"));
        as.put(2, new A("Maria"));
        as.put(3, new A("Eva"));

        Map<Integer, B> bs = new HashMap();
        bs.put(1, new B("Adam"));
        bs.put(2, new B("Edward"));
        bs.put(3, new B("Jon"));

        Stream.concat(
                as.entrySet().stream(),
                bs.entrySet().stream()
        ).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> e.getValue())
                .map(e -> {
                    if (e.get(0).getValue() instanceof A)
                        return new AB((A) e.get(0).getValue(), (B) e.get(1).getValue());
                    return new AB((A) e.get(1).getValue(), (B) e.get(0).getValue());
                })
                .map(ab -> new C(ab.a.name+" " +ab.b.name))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

"The high magic" happens in `Stream.concat` then `groupingBy`. In this two lines we create stream of all entries from both maps. Then we group them by key to map. Elements with the same key (id) will go to one `List<Object>`. Next step is create new stream from grouping map `entrySet().stream()`.

Then we extract value - entries with the same `Id` > `map(e -> e.getValue())`.

Next step is to build `AB` objects and could be omitted but I want to extract type check and cast to another function. Now we have pseudo pair `AB`, that is very nice candidate for create `C` class `map(ab -> new C(ab.a.name+" " +ab.b.name))`.

Classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `AB`:

```
class A {

    final String name;

    A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

class B {

    final String name;

    B(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

class C {

    final String name;

    C(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "C{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

class AB {

    final A a;
    final B b;

    AB(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AB{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", b=" + b +
                '}';
    }
}
```